# installing pygraphviz on Python3.6 (win10, anaconda)

Tags: python-3.6, pygraphviz

I have problems installing pygraphviz, I tried several ways but none succeeded

1.>pip install pygraphviz

Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygraphviz ... error
  Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error

2.>pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

3.>pip install pygraphviz-1.4rc1.tar.gz

Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygraphviz ... error
  Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error

4.>python setup.py install --include-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.38.0/include/graphviz --library-path=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.38.0/lib

'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Why do you use pip in anaconda?

Comment: conda install still not work.

Comment: I am facing this today, Did you succeeded to solve it?